# Can still use application after destroying session or logout

Tags: java, wildfly, keycloak

I am new to keycloak, so there is a high chance I don't understand something going on here.
Im currently trying to understand how to use Keycloak, so I have set up a small demo application:

- Its the application from [IntelliJ JavaEE tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-ee-application.html#deploy-ear) which runs on the root context path `/app`
- I use it dockerized on a Wildfly Server `jboss/wildfly:17.0.0.Final`, WILDFLY keycloak adapter already installed.
- `Traefik` proxy is used to reach the app on the browser using `http://localhost/app` and keycloak using `http://keycloak.localhost`
- Keycloak docker container is reachable from the network using alias `keycloak`, but I use environment variable `KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL=http://keycloak.localhost/auth` to set another URL for frontend related stuff
- I have created a realm `javaee-realm` and one client for my application called `javaee-app`. Also, one user called "user" with a role of "user" is configured in Keycloak.
- When accessing the app in the browser using `http://localhost/app`, I get redirected to Keycloak where I can login as User "user". I get redirected back to the application afterwards.

##### The Problem:

When logging out by destroying the session inside Keycloak Dashboard or by accessing `http://keycloak.localhost/auth/realms/javaee-realm/protocol/openid-connect/logout` the session gets deleted, but I can still use the application. Usually, I would expect to be redirected to Keycloak again. After some time, an error is logged in the application container:

```
16:09:48,285 ERROR [org.keycloak.adapters.RefreshableKeycloakSecurityContext] (default task-1) Refresh token failure status: 400 {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Stale token"}
```

### Wildfly Adapter Configuration `standalone.xml`

```xml
[...]
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:keycloak:1.2">
      <secure-deployment name="javaee-application.war">
           <realm>javaee-realm</realm>
           <auth-server-url>http://keycloak:8080/auth</auth-server-url>
           <ssl-required>none</ssl-required>
           <resource>javaee-app</resource>
           <principal-attribute>preferred_username</principal-attribute>
           <public-client>true</public-client>
      </secure-deployment>
</subsystem>
[...]
```

### My web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">

    <module-name>javaee-application</module-name>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>All other resources</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>user</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>KEYCLOAK</auth-method>
    </login-config>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

### Client Configuration in Keycloak

[image]

The expected behavior occurs when I delete the `JSESSIONID` cookie in my browser. So, after deletion, I get redirected to Keycloak when I try to access the application. But obv this is no solution...

Does anyone know what the problem here is precisely?

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna answer my own question:

In Keycloak, the access token is still valid after logging out even though the session is not active anymore.

It has a default lifetime of 5 minutes I think, so WILDFLY is only going to verify after 5 minutes if the user is still authenticated. As a consequence, the user can still use the application for 5 minutes.

There is probably a way to configure that tokens should be invalidated when the user logs out, but I havent found something like that just yet.